# How do I list taxonomies that have upcoming events in WP? Is there a way to do this without having to query posts first?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'd like to create a list of taxonomies that contain forthcoming events. Dates of events saved as a custom field?

The technique I am using is to query all posts and extract taxonomies before filtering, although this makes the query a little slower.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: probably need to use a combination of a `meta_quey` and `taxonomy_query` to get this done in one `WP_Query`.

Comment: Can you give me a WP Query example for this? My brain isn't working with this:D